# Wordpress insert NOW() in TIMESTAMP column returns all zeros

Tags: wpdb

I want to insert a TIMESTAMP into my column's TIMESTAMP column, but I always get all zeros.

Here is my insert:

```
$now = 'NOW()';

// insert the date into the db
 $wpdb->insert( 
    'wp_date', 
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'date' => $now    
    ), 
    array( 
        '%s',
        '%s'
    ) 
); // end insert
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hadn't tried to reproduce it, but the likely reason is that what you *want* to use in query is SQL function (`NOW()`) but what you *"tell"* WordPress to use is a string.

Declaring its format to be `%s` means it is sanitized and put in quotes, making it something like `'NOW()'` which MySQL probably sees as very invalid timestamp.

You will have to either generate raw SQL query for this (without using insert helper) or generate and provide timestamp string PHP-side.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a raw query and hoped I could sneak it in :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `'NOW()'` in `$wpbd->insert` to set current timestamp. I suggest using WP built-in function `current_time()`. The fist parameter should be `'mysql'` (to get MySQL compatible string). The second specify in which time zone you'd like to recieve the result: `false` is your server local time, `true` is GMT. So, code you need is:

```
$now = current_time('mysql', false);
```

Output of `$now` will be time in your server local time, for example: `2014-07-20 18:46:23`.

Read more about `current_time()` -- http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time